# Тире при обращении

Tags: пунктуация

Они всегда боролись со злом. С тобой борются (поэтому ты) -- зло.

Возможно ли такое написание в случае, где "зло" и обращение и вывод/утверждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что автор ищет новые грамматические формы - более выразительные, чем обычные, а выражение в скобках подсказывает нам смысл, чтобы он не был понят неоднозначно.таким образом, в окончательном тексте мы будем иметь: "Они всегда боролись со злом. С тобой борются -зло.Думаю, что в качестве авторского варианта такое оформление можно оставить. Здесь, вместо обычной запятой при обращении, ставится тире, обозначающее подчеркнутую паузу. Эта пауза и будет говорить нам об особой смысловой нагрузке слова "зло" - "я считаю тебя злом и обращаюсь к тебе".

Comment: Ну как их, эти *новые грамматические формы*, можно воспринимать более выразительными, если они требуют пояснений во избежание неоднозначного понимания? Автор просто промахнулся в новаторском поиске. А скорее, здесь об этом приёме (тире при обращении) можно выразиться попроще и нелестно.

И логика правильная иная, вот такая: "Они всегда боролись со злом. Ты — зло. Поэтому с тобой борются".

Answer (score 2):

И Вам не хворать.

"Зло" в этом предложении, насколько мой неискушенный ум может судить, никак не может выступать в роли обращения. Это сказуемое. "Ты" - подлежащее. Тире между подлежащим, выраженным личным местоимением, и сказуемым, выраженным именительным падежом существительного, как правило, не ставится. Однако тире в этом случае ставится при противопоставлении или при логическом подчеркивании сказуемого.
Перед "поэтому" необходима запятая. 
Если я, конечно, правильно поняла Ваш вопрос, пунктуация в этом предложении будет именно такой.